# Echo value from MYSQL Database to url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that draws information from my MYSQL database. I have a button that I want to echo the id of the row of the information I draw. I can echo all the information to the table but for some reason no idea how to get the information into the URL

I want to use it in the next page in the GET function for additional data being drawn

```
 echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id="<php echo[id], ?>"'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in
```

The unexpected Echo they referring to I think is the second one as the first echo on previous rows in my table I have no issues

Update:

I have this sql string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM new_case WHERE status = 'Active'";
```

In the table I have one row as below and it shows the id of that row.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: You should really rather go and find yourself a beginner’s tutorial that explains the basics of the syntax. Stuff that is as extremely low-level as this, should not be asked about here in the first place, this is not a teaching ground.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the comment as this is low-level for you it is a milestone for me

Comment: @JamesBrown --> $id = $row['id'];
echo "<td><a href='dashboard.php?id=".$id."'><button>Next</button></a></td>";  can you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistake here `<php echo[id], ?>`

you are already inside `PHP`, so dont use  `<?php ?>`

also `echo[id]` is not valid, `PHP` variable start with `$`

So replace your line with below line.

```
 echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id=".$row['id']."'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";
```

Comment: I have tried as above getting new error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in. I have also tried with single ' and then no error but no result in url

Comment: what is your variable for id ?

Comment: id is a number it should show ie 4 the result I am looking for is dashboard.php?id=4

Comment: if $id is  number then it will show as echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id=$id'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";

Comment: if $id not defined then you will get that error

Comment: I have updated my question. in a previous row I call the id to display in the table all I need now is to be displayed in the URL

Comment: ok, so just use `$row['id']`

Comment: unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) 
Now getting this error

Comment: did u used my updated answer ?

Comment: use `echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id=".$row['id']."'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";`

Comment: great, finally worked..!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo at the `echo` function, the syntax of the echo function is `echo <string>` you can see it in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

So calling `echo[id]` is invalid syntax, it expects a string of some sorts (this can be a variable too, as long as it implements a __toString function).

A right way to call it would be like `echo "<td><a href='dashboard.php?id=$id'"...` when you use double quotes PHP will try to interpit the quote and parse any variables written inside of it.

However, it is important to know that is is a security risk to directly output database information into an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id=".$id."'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";
```

instead of

```
 echo "<td> <a href='dashboard.php?id="<php echo[id], ?>"'><button>Next</button></a> </td>";
```